# Using tasker app to prevent phone power off

Tags: tasker

I find it extremely difficult to wake up in the morning, and have to use apps such as "Alarmy" or "sleep as android". However I've discovered that I can just switch my phone off when the alarm is ringing, which means I constantly sleep in for work.

I'm looking to use tasker to disable the power button on my phone while "alarmy" is open, but can't make heads or tails of this app. Any help would be appreciated